# Agregar clase a un div con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente div

```
    <div class="table">
        <div id="scroll-content" class="row">
            <div class="col columnas" id="columna-0">
                <div class="registros title-table">
                    <span>Columna0</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col registros contenido-table di-true to-false d-false fila-0">
                    <span>${item.row}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col registros contenido-table di-true to-false d-false fila-1">
                    <span>${item.row}</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col columnas" id="columna-1">
                <div class="registros title-table">
                    <span>Columna1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col registros contenido-table di-true to-false d-false fila-0">
                    <span>${item.row}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col registros contenido-table di-true to-false d-false fila-1">
                    <span>${item.row}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Necesito aplicarle un estilo al div fila-0 de la columna1, el problema es que no le puedo poner un identificador único (Debido a que es un bucle).

Actualmente solamente puedo agregarselo al div  id="columna-1"

```
    if ($(".contenido-table").hasClass("di-true") && $(".contenido-table").hasClass("to-false")) {
        $('#columna-1').addClass('pruebapruebaprueba');
    }
```

Comment: No comprendo bien que quieres hacer, aplicarlo solo a fila-0 de columna-1?

Comment: si, justo eso mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo desde el identificador, debido a que buscas hacerlo a un lugar concreto:

```js
$('#columna-1 div.fila-0').css({'border-width':'9px', 'border-style':'solid', 'border-color':'red'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
        <div id="scroll-content" class="row">
            <div class="col columnas" id="columna-0">
                <div class="registros title-table">
                    <span>Columna0</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col registros contenido-table di-true to-false d-false fila-0">
                    <span>${item.row}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col registros contenido-table di-true to-false d-false fila-1">
                    <span>${item.row}</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col columnas" id="columna-1">
                <div class="registros title-table">
                    <span>Columna1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="fila-0 col registros contenido-table di-true to-false d-false ">
                    <span>${item.row}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col registros contenido-table di-true to-false d-false fila-1">
                    <span>${item.row}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Con `$('#columna-1 div.fila-0')` obtienes el elemento con la clase `fila-0` de `columna-1`

Answer (score 0):

Práctico, sencillo y sin complicaciones. Piensa como si lo que va dentro de $("") fuesen los elementos de css. Y que, para aplicar un estilo a al hijo nodo de un padre nodo lo llamas de esta forma

> #padre .hijo { /*estilo*/ }
> #columna-1 .fila-0

solo que sin los corchetes.

> $('#columna-1 .fila-0')

```
  if ($(".contenido-table").hasClass("di-true") && $(".contenido-table").hasClass("to-false")) {
            $('#columna-1 .fila-0').addClass('pruebapruebaprueba');
        }
```